# React-native: why after init statment I have only index.js

Tags: react-native

After I use: react-native init test
in the folder there is only index.js file and not the index.android.js, index.ios.js files and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

That is how it is supposed to be. If you are looking for the files that you need to import into Xcode and its Android analog, they are located in the ios and android folders respectively. For Xcode you need `test.xcodeproj`.

Answer (score 0):

After [this update](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.49.0), new projects only have a single entry point, index.js, instead of index.android.js and index.ios.js.